# ExtJS5 how not to submit empty filefield

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, form-submit, extjs5

I have a form with several filefields which I use to implement multiupload ability. Everything works fine, but when I set paths to files not for all fields, my form submits empty text. I read that setting

```
submitEmptyText : false,
```

config in form.submit() function will solve my problem, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set emptyText in config ?

As description in [submitEmptyText of Ext.form.action.Action](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609074039/http://docs.sencha.com:80/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-cfg-submitEmptyText), it will send value configured in `emptyText`.

As filefield , you may need to review [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609074039/http://docs.sencha.com:80/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-emptyText) .

What should be "empty value" if user did not send file ? or you should enforce user to send file with [allowBlank](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609074039/http://docs.sencha.com:80/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-allowBlank) ?